# How to get memory usage of a process with .NET CF 3.5?

Tags: memory, process, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am looking for a way to read the current memory usage of a Windows Mobile process.

I started out with accessing the actual process object. To get `processId` to be passed to `Process.GetProcessById(int processId)` method I followed [this](http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/programming/windows-cemobile-get-process-list-c/) solution.

Unfortunately, .NET CF 3.5 API for `System.Diagnostics.Process` does not provide any properties / methods to work with the process memory.

There must be a way to do that since tools such as *FDCSoft Task Manager* display memory usage for each WM process along with much more process data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the CF BCL that's going to give you that information.  You'll need to P/Invoke the [Toolhelp Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914815.aspx) and build up a heap list then sum those up to get total process usage.  Generally, the call order will look something like this:

- Call `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, ensuring you pass in the `TH32CS_SNAPHEAPLIST` flag
- Call `Heap32ListFirst` for the first `HEAPLIST32` structure
- Keep calling `Heap32ListNext` for more structures until it return FALSE
- Call `Call`CloseToolhelp32Snapshot`